# Changing username and password in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I tried to change MySQL username and password:

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET user='myuser', password=PASSWORD('mypassword') WHERE user='root'; 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec) Rows matched: 0 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES; Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

but now mysql won't let me in and can't try anything else. :/

Comment: Well you might have changed the user but the new user has no PRIVILEGES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try to create new user

1. CREATE USER 'new_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'.
2. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'new_user'@'localhost';
3. FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

### To change Password of root user:

*UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;*

### To change Password for myuser :

UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='myuser';

Answer (score 1):

Messing with MySQL's system tables in the `mysql` schema is unwise unless you have serious experience with MySQL internals. For information, privileges are stored in [several other tables in the `mysql` schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant-table-structure.html), which must be updated in cascade should you decide to manually edit the `mysql.user` table.

This is not recommended at all.

If you want to "rename" a user, you should create a new user and grant the same privileges as the old one. You can leverage the [`SHOW GRANTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-grants.html) 
command. It outputs valid `GRANT` statements, which you can easily adapt for your new user.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should create a new user if you required, instead of renaming to root user.

Further if you have any other admin user with grant privileges then you can connect by that user.

If you don't have any other admin user and not able to connect mysql by any way then you need to follow below steps to unlock root user.

Step1: add below 2 line in your my.cnf or my.ini file.
skip-grant-tables
skip-networking

Step2: restart mysql service.

Step2: connect mysql without password (just pass mysql command without username and password) and change user name again to root by below command.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET user='root' WHERE USER='myuser'; flush privileges;
```

Step3: Remove newly added 2 lines from my.cnf file and restart mysql service.

Step4: Now try with below command-

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

pass password whatever you changed for myuser as we just changed username but not password at this time.